# Linq to SQL: Why decimal field get truncated on Insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, decimal, decimal-point

I have a column defined as `decimal(10,6)`. When I try to save the model with the value `10.12345`, in the database I saved as 10.123400. The last digit ("5") is truncated.

Why is the number default to only 4 digits in LINQ (for decimal) and how can I avoid this for all columns in my models? The solution I found was to use `DbType="Decimal(10,6)"`, but I have a lot of columns in this situation and the change should be applied to all, and I don't see it like a good idea.

Is there a way to change this behavior without changing all the decimal columns?

Thanks

Comment: What is the *current* database field typed as? A float? (Which has ~7 digits of precision.)

Comment: The field has the type decimal(10,6).

Comment: I mean, to what *CLR/property* type is it mapped?

Comment: Is mapped to decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper DbType, `decimal(10, 6)` in this case.

The reason for this is simple - while .NET's `decimal` is actually a (decimal) floating point (the decimal point can move), MS SQL's isn't. It's a fixed "four left of decimal point, six right of decimal point". When LINQ passes the `decimal` to MS SQL, it *has* to use a specific SQL decimal - and the default simply happens to use four for the scale. You could always use a `decimal` big enough for whatever value you're trying to pass, but that's very impractical - for one, it will pretty much eliminate execution plan caching, because each different `decimal(p, s)` required will be its own separate query. If you're passing multiple decimals, this means you'll pretty much never get a cached plan; ouch.

In effect, the command doesn't send the value `10.12345` - it sends `10123450` (not entirely true, but just bear with me). Thus, when you're passing the parameter, you *must* know the scale - you need to send `10` as `10000000`, for example. The same applies when you're not using LINQ - using `SqlCommand` manually has the same "issue", and you have to use a specific precision and scale.

If you're wary of modifying all those columns manually, just write a script to do it for you. But you do need to maintain the proper data types manually, there's no way around it.